# Layout problems in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, layout

Currently having a big problem with the layout of a site. It works fine in every other browser but for some reason, in IE, the menu's aren't expanding when they are clicked on. The screenshot below is how the list should look when a button is clicked on, this has also pushed down the elements of the bottom of the website such as the footer and images. The website address is www.citybathcoll.ac.uk if you want to see it first hand. From what I can see, it might be an unclosed tag but I can't see anything that stands out. Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsuhj.jpg

Comment: "the screenshot below", which one? And i guess the website is `www.citybathcoll.ac.uk`?

Comment: code or jsfiddle plz?

Comment: Sorry guys, edited the post, included screenshot now.